# magento catalog search add result count in url

Tags: php, magento, observer-pattern

I want to add result count in search url. The default url is like `domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=queries`
But I want add result count in url like,

```
`domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=queries&count=50`
```

I tried with below event observer

```
controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_result_index
```

and **Observer.php**

```
 <?php
    class PackgeName_ModuleName_Model_Observer {
        // the product list block name in layout
        const RESULT_BLOCK_NAME = 'search_result_list';
        public function loadResult(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
            $currentUrl = Mage::helper ( 'core/url' )->getCurrentUrl ();

            $block = Mage::app ()->getLayout ()->getBlock ( self::RESULT_BLOCK_NAME );
            if ($block) {

                $collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection ();

                /**
                 * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
                 */
                $count = $collection->getSize ();

                $resultUrl = $currentUrl . '&count=' . $count;

                if ($resultUrl) {

                    Mage::app ()->getResponse ()->setRedirect ( $resultUrl );
                    exit (); // stop everything else
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem is its again triggered. So it go to endless loop. Any Idea's to fix this issue or Is there any way to achieve this ? Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the right answer as i am new to Magento as well..
But i added textfield in my form.mini.phtml and put it below the "q" textfield like this

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="abc" value="" >
```

and it will result : 
domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=queries&abc=

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check that the count is not in the request uri:

```
    public function loadResult(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

       $count = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('count');

       if (!$count){

           $currentUrl = Mage::helper ( 'core/url' )->getCurrentUrl ();

           $block = Mage::app ()->getLayout ()->getBlock ( self::RESULT_BLOCK_NAME );
```

Comment: It will again hit the result page and again the  same observer will be trigger. So it goes to endless loop..